# "Unknown Label type" decision tree classifier with floats

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree

I want to use a decision tree to predict the value of a float based on 6 features that are also float values. I realise that a decision tree may not be the best method, but I am comparing multiple methods to try and understand them better

The error I am getting is "Unknown label type" on my y training data list. I have read that "DecisionTreeClassifier" accepts float values, and that typically the values are converted to float 32 anyway. I am explicit setting the values in my list to float32 yet there still seems to be a problem, can anybody help?

sample of my x training data (features_x_train)  :

```
[[  2.49496743e-01   6.07936502e-01  -4.20752168e-01  -3.88045199e-02
   -7.59323120e-01  -7.59323120e-01]
 [  4.07418489e-01   5.36915325e-02   2.95270741e-01   1.87122121e-01
    9.89770174e-01   9.89770174e-01]]
```

sample of my y training data (predict_y_train): `[ -7.59323120e-01   9.89770174e-01]`

Code...

```
df_train = wellbeing_df[feature_cols].sample(frac=0.9)

#Split columns into predictor and result
features_x_train = 
np.array(df_train[list(top_features_cols)].values).astype(np.float32)
predict_y_train = np.asarray(df_train['Happiness score'], dtype=np.float32)


#Setup decision tree
decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(features_x_train, predict_y_train) 
#Train tree on 90% of available data
```

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-a44a03982bdb> in <module>()
     19 #Setup decision tree
     20 decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
---> 21 decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(features_x_train, predict_y_train) #Train tree on 90% of available data
     22 
     23 #Test on remaining 10%

C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    175 
    176         if is_classification:
--> 177             check_classification_targets(y)
    178             y = np.copy(y)
    179 

C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.pyc in check_classification_targets(y)
    171     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
    172             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 173         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
    174 
    175 

ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[ -7.59323120e-01],
       [  9.89770174e-01],
```

Also If I change the list to string values then the code runs

Answer (score 2):

Decision Tree **Classifier**, is, well... a classifier. Classifier is an estimator of function from some arbitrary space (usually R^d) into **finite** space of values, called **label space**. Consequently python (scikit-learn) expects you to pass something that is label-like, thus: integer, string, etc. floats are not a typical encoding form of **finite** space, they are used for **regression**.

Thus is short you seem to be confusing classification and regression. How to distinguish?

- if you have y as floats, but only **a finite number of different values** can be obtained, and **all of them** are obtained in training set, then this is classification - just convert your values to strings or integers and you are good to go.
- if you have y as floats, and this are actuall **real** values, and you can have plenty of values, even not seen in the training set and you expect your model to somehow "interpolate" this is **regression** and you are supposed to use DecisionTreeRegressor instead.

Answer (score -1):

use sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()